# Combining a website with android

Tags: php, android, eclipse

I am trying to make a register app using Eclipse. I want the user to be able to fill in information in the app and click a button that will send the information to a PHP website.

However, it seems that when I click the button it doesn't send the information (display name, username and password) to the website.

Here are the lines of code of the app:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText displayname, username, password, responseText;
String displaynameText, usernameText, passwordText;
Button registerbtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    displayname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);        
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    responseText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.responseLog);
    registerbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    displaynameText = displayname.getText().toString();
    usernameText = username.getText().toString();
    passwordText = password.getText().toString();

    final HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    final HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://anschluss.webuda.com/register.php");

    final List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("displayname", displaynameText));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", usernameText));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", passwordText));

    registerbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
            } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try{
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                responseText.setText(response.toString());
            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

As for the PHP I have this:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST)){

$displayname = $_POST["displayname"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

if(!empty($displayname) && !empty($username) && !empty($password)){

    $mysql_host = "hostname";
    $mysql_database = "database";
    $mysql_user = "username";
    $mysql_password = "password";

    mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
    mysql_select_db($mysql_database);

    $checkDisplayName = mysql_query("SELECT displayname FROM info WHERE displayname = '$displayname'");
    $displayNameAantal = mysql_num_rows($checkDisplayName);
    $checkUsername = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM info WHERE username = '$username'");
    $usernameAantal = mysql_num_rows($checkUsername);

    if($displayNameAantal == 0){
        if($usernameAantal == 0){
            $insertQuery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO info(displayname, username, password) VALUES ('$displayname', ' $username', '$password')");
            $returnValue = "Succes";
            echo $returnValue;
        } else{
            $returnValue = "Username is already taken";
            echo $returnValue;
        }
    } else{
        $returnValue = "Displayname is already taken";
        echo $returnValue;
    }
} else{
    $returnValue = "Something is left blank";
    echo $returnValue;
}
} 

?>
```

Please let me know if you know how to make this work.

Comment: Make sure you get the post values in your php script..
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>

Comment: you should remove hostname and database info from your code posted here, this is very valuable information for hackers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's something conceptually very wrong in your code: **You are accessing the network inside the UI thread** (=== blocking the user interface). Check if Android isn't complaining about that! Network access **must be done in a thread outside the UI**, using an `AsyncTask` (Android's preferred way) or manually spawning a `Thread` (classic Java way).

If there are no other errors related to the HTTP Post, probably this is what's happening. However, if you fix other possible errors and the HTTP post is sent, you will get a **Called From Wrong Thread** exception.

Comment: Thank you so much! You were spot-on; using AsyncTask fixed the problem and the app is now working like a charm!

Comment: glad to hear! I'd also recommend you to hash the password with md5 for example so it isn't POSTed in clear format. Also you should store it hashed in the DB so if someone steals your DB you don't compromise all your users passwords !

Answer (score 0):

`response.toString()` is incorrect try using this to get the response:

```
EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it isn't getting any response. When I look at the database it seems as if the information isn't even being processed. Any idea?

Comment: Maybe your connection to the db is not working, try using `or die('Error: '. mysql_error() )` with your mysql statements

Comment: The connection to the database seems to be fine. The post values are also correct when I try to register via the website itself.